# Restore Windows to Size They Were Previous to Being Minimized

Tags: c#, winapi

I'm trying to use WinAPI to bring any open window to the foreground. I've tried many different ways of accomplishing this but none that worked out perfectly. Methods I've tried include `SwitchToThisWindow`, `BringWindowToTop`, `SetActiveWindow`, and `SetForegroundWindow` using the `AttachInputThread` and they all tended to fail if the target window was minimized. More recently I've tried `OpenIcon` and `ShowWindow` (with the RESTORE command) to unminimize windows, but that too has presented a problem, in that, both of those methods unminimize the window to it's "Normal" or "Original" state regardless of whether it was "Normal" or "Maximized" before it was minimized.

The current solution I can think of is to intercept the minimize message to any open window and store its state before it's minimized and restore it using that stored state. However, this would require me hooking into every process I'd want to restore which I'd really rather not do.

So my question is, how do unminimize a window to the state it was in before it was minimized?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is correct. You have to store the window size so you can "reconstitute it" to the same size. You should also store position, as well as size, if you want it to look correct. Much of this is abstracted if you don't dig into the bowels like this.

Comment: I'm okay with it being abstracted if that's an option. Are there ways to manipulate windows outside of one's application without using WinAPI?